# Node.js pipe image into memory and display it

Tags: node.js

I am making a Node.js/Electron application that downloads and displays images. I am downloading an image from the internet using request. I want to save this image in memory and display it without saving the file on the local hard drive. I am aware I could accomplish what I am asking here by inserting `<img src="url">` into the DOM, but this is a heavily simplified version of my code and what I am trying to accomplish can not be done with that.

```
var image = fs.createWriteStream(?); // Is there anyway to save the image to memory?
request(url).pipe(image);
$('img').exampleScriptToSetImage(image); // And is there any way to display that image in a element without saving it to the local disk and loading its path?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed! You can pipe your requested image data into a concat stream, convert the buffer to base64, and set the base64 encoding as your image source.

```
var path = require('path')
var request = require('request') // or hyperquest, simple-get, etc...
var concat = require('concat-stream')

var image = request(url)
image.pipe(concat({ encoding: 'buffer' }, function (buf) {
  var ext = path.extname(file.name).slice(1) // assuming you have the file name
  if (ext === 'svg') ext = 'svg+xml'
  var src = 'data:image/' + ext + ';base64,' + buf.toString('base64')
  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = src
  document.body.appendChild(img)
})
```